# Get div value from a string

Tags: jquery, string, html

I have the following string

```
str ='<div id="example">Text</div><div id="test">Test</div>';
```

how can I get the example and test content with jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the text to a jQuery object and then use standard traversing methods

```
str ='<div id="example">Text</div><div id="test">Test</div>';
var live_str = $('<div>',{html:str});

var example = live_str.find('#example').text();
// example variable now holds 'Text'

var test = live_str.find('#test').text();
// example variable now holds 'Test'
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/FJSm6/

---

As you see i set the string as the html of another element, because otherwise the divs would be at the top level and you would not be able to traverse them with `.find()`..

Answer (score 3):

You can always create min-DOMs (if you wish) by passing a valid HTML to jQuery:

```
$(str).wrap('<p>').parent().find('div').text();
```

so:

```
var textContent = $(str).wrap('<p>').parent().find('#example').text();
var testContent = $(str).wrap('<p>').parent().find('#test').text();
```

Comment: did you try this ? it does not work because the divs will be the root elements, and `.find()` will not work as it looks for descendants of the current element..

Comment: Then this is the cure: `$(str).wrap('<div>').find('#example').text();`

Comment: Yes, it's not working, I did in this way, and It doesn't work, this is the reason why I asked this questin

Comment: @Saeed, i know the cure, just mentioning that you should edit your answer. BTW, **that is not the cure** because `.wrap` returns the original object not the wrapped. so you should use `$(str).wrap('<div>').parent().find('#example').text();` or directly create an element and set the contents to be the string as i mention in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to store the content in a var and work with that:

```
var example = $('#example').text(), test = $('#test').val();
```

You can also get the contents using .html() if you would like to also grab the html tags if necessary.